# GKE killing pods when there is more than 5 of them

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-hpa

I have a k8s cluster deployed on GKE, there is one "main" nodepool containing 1 node, for all the deployments and one nodepool containing 1 node for [kube-ip](https://github.com/doitintl/kubeip).

On the main nodepool, I would like to deploy 10 replicas of one of my application (flask API). However GKE is contantly killing my pods when the number exceed 5 to get the pod number back to 5.

I tried to modify the values in my differents yaml files (`deployment.yaml` and `horizontalPodScheduler.yaml`)

horizontalPodScheduler.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
    env: production
  name: my-app-hpa
  namespace: production
spec:
  maxReplicas: 20
  metrics:
    - resource:
        name: cpu
        targetAverageUtilization: 80
      type: Resource
  minReplicas: 10
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-app
```

deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
    env: production
  name: my-app
  namespace: production
spec:
  replicas: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
      env: production
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
        env: production
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: my-pool
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/my_project_id/github.com/my_org/my-app
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: my-app-1
```

Even when I set those values, GKE is always overwritting them to 5 replicas:

Here is the resources summary for my main node, you can see there is plenty of resources to deploy the replicas (it's a pretty simple API)

I also tried to use the "scale" button on GKE UI, but results are the same...

[image: resources]

Comment: hope you are not runnin the argo CD or anything is overwriting the files again and again or changing it.

Comment: I don't think I use argo cd

Comment: Very obvious but have you increased your GCP Compute Engine quota?

Comment: I can't see how it could help, the node is already running and there is enough resources on it to schedule at least 6 pods, and max I can have is still 5

Comment: Could it be that since it is an auto-scaler, it is scaling down. Could you possibly do multiple concurrent calls to your flask API so GKE can "scale up" - I haven't used GKE in a while, but definitely have a look at your GCP quotas. Compute Engine/GKE both!

Comment: Yes but I specified the minReplicas to be at least 10, I agree it is load balanced but it should be balanced between the limits I set : min 10 and max 20

Comment: Is there anything in logs or events ? Does `gcloud container operations list` show anything related ?